# Algorithm Complexity in a Graph

Tags: performance, graph, time-complexity

I want to delete a graph which uses an adjacency list. The algorithm to erase the list has a complexity of O(N) where N is the number of elements in the list and works properly ,the vertexes are also connected using a linked list, I would like to see if my algorithm to delete the graph is correct and, if so, it's complexity.

```
1º If the graph doesn't exist, exit.
2º If there are no vertexes, erase graph, exit.
3º Delete the adjacency list of the first vertex, if it exists.
4º Delete the first vertex.
5º Repeat the function recursively.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: the question doesn't seem to have much to do with java or C. The complexity of it, which is what you're asking for, is going to be the same in all languages

Comment: I agree and accept your suggestion to edit.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it looks correct.

I'm only slightly unsure about step 5

> 5º Repeat the function recursively.

From the first 4 steps I assumed you had a graph object that contains a list of verteces. Then the logical solution is to iterate over each vertex deleting it's edges, then the vertex itself.

But then you specifically describes step 5 with the word "recursively".

So I assume that means that for each of the verteces, you first store it's neighbours, then delete the edges, then the node itself, and then iterate over the stored neighbours.

Now you're checking too much. If you have a fully interconnected graph of n nodes, you're checking each vertex n-1 times. Only the first time you actually do work though. So I'm not 100% sure if this still counts as O(n) or not.

If you keep a list of all the verteces you still have to do, and when checking a vertex, you add his neighbours to that list only if they're not already in it. (For example if you use a Set in java, that can't contain doubles). Then it shouldn't be a problem.

After each iteration, you just take the next vertex out of the todo-list and repeat until that list is empty. Each connected vertex will have been put exactly once into that list. So total complexity is O(n).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what I meant in step 5 was after deleting the list and the vertex itself I would do the same thing, until I have no vertexes to delete. I forgot to mention  I have a pointer to the first element of the vertexes list and each vertex has a pointer to it's adjacency list, so checking if a list exists is easy, I assume. Is it still correct?

Comment: yes and no. Yes in the sense that you do almost no work when checking an already completed node again, so you could argue that those extra checks on previously deleted nodes don't count. But what if you have a graph with 1000 nodes, all interconnected. This means you do 1000 actual deletes and around 999000 checks for a node that is already deleted (depending on how you implemented it exactly). Even if those checks are cheap, you're doing O(n²) of them. So then I would say no, it's not O(n).

Comment: I also know how many vertexes there are, maybe change the algorithm to see if the Number of vertexes is zero?

Comment: As I said it already depends on your current implementation. If at each step you just fetch the next available one to delete it's possible that you only check each one exactly once. Without your actual code it's difficult to see the correctness :) I think you already have a correct one, but I'm just not 100% certain of it.